# Why am I getting a TypeError?

Tags: python, class

My goal with this program is to record 4 pieces of information (Employee Number, Employe Name, Shift Number, and Hourly Pay Rate) and then display them. I need to use classes in this program.

Here is the Class code:

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number - number

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

class ProductionWorker(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, number,
                 shift, payRate):

        Employee.__init__(self, name, number)

        self.__shift = shift
        self.__payRate = payRate

    def set_shift(self, shift):
        self.__shift = shift

    def set_payRate(self, payRate):
        self.__payRate = payRate

    def get_shift(self):
        return self.__shift

    def get_payRate(self):
        return self.__payRate
```

Here is the code that imports the class code and executes it:

```
import employee

name = input('Name: ')
number = input('Employee Number: ')
shift = input('Shift number (Enter 1 for day and 2 for night): ')
payRate = input('Hourly Pay Rate: ')

myEmployee = employee.ProductionWorker(name, number,
                           shift, payRate)

print('--------------------')
print('Employee Information')
print('--------------------')
print('Name:', myEmployee.get_name())
print('Employee Number:', myEmployee.get_number())
print('Customer number:', myEmployee.get_Shift())
print('Hourly Pay Rate:', myEmployee.get_payRate())
```

Okay, fixed type of:

```
myEmployee = employee.Employee(name, number,
                           shift, payRate)
```

to:

```
myEmployee = employee.ProductionWorker(name, number,
                           shift, payRate)
```

but now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Homework 2/Chapter 13/Employee and Production Worker Class.py", line 9, in <module>
        shift, payRate)
      File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Homework 2/Chapter 13\employee.py", line 24, in __init__
        Employee.__init__(self, name, number)
      File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Homework 2/Chapter 13\employee.py", line 5, in __init__
        self.__number - number
    AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute '_Employee__number'
```

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: `myEmployee = employee.Employee(name, number,shift, payRate)` .. That calls the employee class .. you should call ProductionWorker .. You need to revise how inheritance works.

Comment: You're calling the `__init__` for `Employee` like it's the one for `ProductionWorker`

Comment: Have you heard of Python "properties"? Python is not Java...so forget this setter and getter crude code.

Comment: Agreed with Maulwurfn. Don't use getter and setter methods; just make the attribute public. If you need to add logic to it later, use properties.

Comment: Yes, please, stop writing Java in Python!

Comment: I don't know Java. I was writing with setters/getters because my teacher asked me to for this specific question. Otherwise, I wouldn't have used them. Thank you for the insite though. =)

Comment: Why is there evil in the world!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
myEmployee = employee.Employee(name, number,
                       shift, payRate)
```

to

```
myEmployee = employee.ProductionWorker(name, number,
                       shift, payRate)
```

Also, a piece of advice: writing getters and setters is generally [frowned upon in Python](http://tomayko.com/writings/getters-setters-fuxors). Just make the members public and get/set them like:

```
myEmployee.name = "David"
print myEmployee.name
```

Comment: I reworked my code to fix this issue, but I am getting another error. Any ideas? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Alternatively, use properties. If you ever need to change the flow of data from the perspective of a class or add some universal logic, it is much simpler to modify one method rather than many.

Comment: @AlexKiss: You meant to write `self.__number = number`, not `self.__number - number`. However, I suggest you do take heed of the suggestions above and make it public (`self.number = number`)!

Comment: Don't use getter/setters or properties for this code: use plain-old attributes.

Comment: The only reason why I am using getters/setters is because my teacher asked for that specifically. Normally I wouldn't. Thanks again for all of the tips and insite!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the following lines:

```
myEmployee = employee.Employee(name, number,
                       shift, payRate)
```

to

```
myEmployee = employee.ProductionWorker(name, number,
                       shift, payRate)
```

I guess that might be just a typo..

Answer (score 2):

You mistook `Employee` with `ProductionWorker` in your main code.

Replace

```
myEmployee = employee.Employee(name, number,shift, payRate)
```

by

```
myEmployee = employee.ProductionWorker(name, number,shift, payRate)
```